# Animated using sprite sheet in LibGdx, wont show on mobile

Tags: java, libgdx

I animated sprite using sprite sheet and it works fine when i run on desktop but once i install on mobile device that animated sprite is shown as black square. What is the problem?

Using ubuntu 16.04 and android studio.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

animation = new Animation(FRAME_LENGTH, TextureRegion.split(new Texture("name.png"), SIZE, SIZE)[0]);

batch.draw((TextureRegion) animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime), x, y);
```

Comment: How do you expect us to find the problem, without seeing your code?

Comment: as i wrote it works fine on desktop so code isn't problem, animated sprite doesn't work on mobile. it is not shown.

Comment: Just because your code works on desktop, that doesn't mean it isn't your code that's the problem on mobile.

Comment: standard way, 
batch.draw((TextureRegion)variable[number].getKeyFrame(statetime,true),x,y);

Comment: Are you using AssetManager​ as static ?

Comment: - animation = new Animation(FRAME_LENGTH, TextureRegion.split(new Texture("name.png"), SIZE, SIZE)[0]);

- batch.draw((TextureRegion) animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime), x, y);

Comment: Perhaps it is working but because of differences in resolution on desktop and mobile, the sprite is simply not visible on your mobile screen. Maybe try moving the sprite to test, but the best approach would be to use a camera and viewport.

Comment: orthographicCamera = new OrthographicCamera(); viewport = new StretchViewport(WIDTH, HEIGHT, orthographicCamera); 
viewport.apply(); orthographicCamera.position.set(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, 0); 
orthographicCamera.update(); 

and 
batch.setProjectionMatrix(orthographicCamera.combined);

Comment: now it doesn show anything on phone, just background color

Comment: That seems alright. Could you screenshot what you see in desktop and what you see in android. That would help a lot.